# Evolving strategies for prisoners dilemma

Tags: genetic-algorithm, game-theory

Can somebody help me in understanding this [article](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~golbeck/downloads/JGolbeck_prison.pdf)? I have understood what prisoners dilemma is but not able to understand the stimuli part and how the fitness is calculated.

Answer (score 2):

**For the stimulation part:**
There are 6 persons:
so the possibility is 2 power 6 = 64;
2 means either 
**C**  or **D** 
 consider if **0** person is defective **[0][0][0][0][0][0]** 

**1** person is defective **[0][0][0][0][0][*1*]** 

**2** person is defective **[0][0][0][0][*1*][0]**

Hope you can got it..